# Loop within a date range for each month and each day

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have two text-boxes which are used to select a From and a To date. I need to have a loop where the outer loop will be for a year and the inner loop will run for each month.

Problem is with the code below, if I choose 11/01/2011 and 06/30/2012, my month loop runs once for month 11. After that the loop exits.. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using the code below to look into a SharePoint Calendar List (using CAML query) and fetch number of times 3, 5 consecutive days a certain room is available excluding week ends. Idea is to use CAML query to get the number of free days for each month and keep repeating till the last selected month.

```
int year = 0, month = 0; 
for (year = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Year; year <= Calendar2.SelectedDate.Year; year++)
{
  int i = year;
  for (month = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Month; month <= Calendar2.SelectedDate.Month; month++)
  {
    int j = month;
  }
}
```

Comment: Come on guys (as in everyone who's answering), who want's to read code that won't fit on the screen?

Comment: Please leave "C#:" out of your titles. See "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow and my first post. I didn't know about the formatting. As for the title, I have seen forums that are divided in sections and since I didn't see such a setup, I thought tagging with C# might help someone who knows C# to see my question easily!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to iterate through each month between the 2 dates. If so, this should work:

```
var dt2 = Calendar2.SelectedDate.Year;
var current = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
while (current < dt2)
{
  current = current.AddMonths(1);
  //do your work for each month here
}
```

Comment: +1 That's actually the answer I wanted to give, but I haven't worked with the date stuff much lately and didn't remember what the 'AddMonth' method was called (or if it even existed).

Answer (score 7):

Would something like this work?

```
for (DateTime date = Calendar1.SelectedDate; date < Calendar2.SelectedDate; date = date.AddMonths(1))
{
 //code
}
```

Comment: The post marked as answer won't even compile. Calendar2.SelectedDate.Year returns an int, so while (current < dt2) will fail.  And the variables current and dt2 are also outside of the while loop, which is unnecessary.

Comment: +1 I've used this before; I like the way you can write a `for loop` around the DateTime data type :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I love this approach.  I personally think it's more elegant than the marked answer.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your starting and ending number for your inner loop should be conditional.

If you're on the start year then the start month should be the selected month; otherwise it should be 1.

If you're on the end year then the end month should be the selected month; otherwise it should be 12.

Example:

```
var startYear = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Year;
var endYear = Calender2.SelectedDate.Year;
var startMonth = Calender1.SelectedDate.Month;
var endMonth = Calender2.SelectedDate.Month;

for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++)
{
    var sm = year == startYear ? startMonth : 1;
    var em = year == endYear ? endMonth : 12;

    for (var month = sm; month <= em; month++)
    {

    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I went with a solution which was modeled on BlackSpy.

Answer (score 0):

For the start year, you need to start your inner loop from the appropriate month, and run through all 12 months, except on the end year, where you should run to the appropriate month.  Something like this should work:

```
int year = 0, month = 0;    
for (year = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Year; year <= Calendar2.SelectedDate.Year; year++)
{
    int i = year;

    for (month = (i==Calendar1.SelectedDate.Year ? Calendar1.SelectedDate.Month : 1); month <= (i==Calendar2.SelectedDate.Year ? Calendar2.SelectedDate.Month : 12); month++)
    {
        int j = month;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Function return First day in Month For Date --example : 01-09-2012

public static  DateTime FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
     {
         return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);

     }

//code used to loop throw a Date range for each month
DateTime FirstDayInMonth = FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(Date);
DateTime TempDay = FirstDayInMonth;
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(FirstDayInMonth.Year, FirstDayInMonth.Month);

for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
   {
     System.Out.Println(TempDay.toString());
     TempDay.AddDays(1);
   }

//then used code for each month in year (simple loop from 1-12)..
```

Comment: @marijn I like this code. Just quick note, the TempDay will not increment your example, you need to reassign in the loop. TempDay = TempDay.AddDays(1);

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.DaysInMonth(2020, 1));

            var start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            var end = new DateTime(2000, 12, 31);

            end = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(end.Year, end.Month));
            var diff = Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                                 .Select(e => start.AddMonths(e))
                                 .TakeWhile(e => e <= end)
                                 .Select(e => e);
            foreach (var item in diff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Date - " + item.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                Console.WriteLine("End Date - " + item.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(item.Year, item.Month) - 1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
            }
        }
```